# Adding Reference Frames Velocities to Create Acceleration

Tags: reference-frames, velocity, angular-velocity

The earth’s rotational velocity at the equator is about 0.5km/sec. It’s orbital velocity around the sun is roughly 30km/sec. Over the course of a 24 hour period earth’s rotational velocity adds to or subtracts from its orbital velocity. The maximum changes occur at noon and midnight. This creates acceleration as the these velocities add 30.5km/sec and subtract 29.5km/sec. This means we are experiencing an acceleration or deceleration of 1km/sec. Has or can this acceleration be measured? 
Note: I have not included “minor” details such as the tilt of the ecliptic plane etc.

Comment: I have removed the word constantly

Comment: You are taking about acceleration, but the units are velocity?

Comment: @Eli isn’t acceleration a change in velocity?

Comment: Acceleration is delta v divided by delta t . $a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$